# adjust margin top of div2 as div1 grows

Tags: jquery, css

I have two div2 . div1 increases height based on few requirements what i want is adjust div2 margin top as div1 increases height . this all happen when submit button is clicked

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(){
    $('#right2').css('margin-top',$("#right").height()+20);
});
});
</script>
```

but margin top adjusts and dissapearing off. if i use return false other functionalities not working

Comment: please share html and css

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below mentioned solution.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#submit").click(function(e){ 
           e.preventDefault():
           $('#right2').css('margin-top',$("#right").height()+20); 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

This will help you.